# Reducing number of DB queries when using views, search_api and relationships

Tags: views, entities, performance, search

I have a view which uses search_api (and solr) to get a list of nodes, and then displays selected fields, including some from a relationship to commerce_product

This is resulting in about a thousand database queries to display about 20 nodes, which I think is inefficient.

Digging in further, it looks like search_api returns a list of nids, which are then loaded with a single invocation of entity_load (which causes several DB queries as field_attach_load loads each of the bundle's fields in turn, loading values for all nodes at once)

But when it comes to the commerce_products in the relationship, these are loaded one-by-one somewhere during the field render process, rather than all in one go. So the total number of queries is close to (number of results) x (number of fields) instead of just (number of fields) like it would be without the relationship.

(Yes, I have quite a few fields)

Is there any way I can get Views to load all of the referenced entities in one go, rather than in this inefficient one-by-one manner?

[image: screenshot of views UI]

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way get Views to load all of the referenced entities in one go? No, there's not much you can easily change to fix that.

There's a lot of behaviour built in so that Drupal can handle multilingual data or different data storage back ends like MongoDB.

If you're not already doing so, you can use [entitycache module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache) to lighten the load. For cached entities, you will eliminate a lot of queries.

FYI, Entitycache will not work on its own. You will need to integrate with a cache back end like [Redis](https://www.drupal.org/project/redis) or [Memcache](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache). See the module documentation and READMEs for configuration details.